# How has this been simplified?

Tags: factoring

[image]

I have tried to undersatnd how this step works, it shows a rather messy equation on the top line. Then the line below is one step taken to simplfy. But I can't quite figure out what has happend.

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: A common factor of $9x^2 + 3$ was taken out of the two terms in the numerator.

Comment: Does this help? The 2nd line is $2(9x^2 + 3)\cdot \left[18x(2x-8) \; - \; (9x^2 + 3) \right]$ A common factor of $2$ and a common factor of $9x^2 + 3$ are taken out. I've used square brackets to indicate what I used to call (when I taught algebra) the "factoring parentheses".

Comment: Easy to see with color-coding:$$36x\color{red}{(9x^2+3)}(2x-8)-2\color{red}{(9x^2+3)^2}=\color{red}{(9x^2+3)}\bigg(36x(2x-8)-2(9x^2+3)\bigg)$$(ignoring the $2$ that is also pulled out). In other words, $ab+ac=a(b+c)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above expression, you have a confusing expression:

$$36x\left(9x^2+3\right)\left(2x-8\right)-2\left(9x^2+3\right)^2$$

One way to see what happened is to simplify it by letting $y=9x^2+3$, and let $z=2x-8$ then substitute to get:

$$36x(y)(z)-2(y^{2})$$

We did the above step to be able to "see" the factors clearly.

Now, factor out $(2y)$ to get:

$$(2y)(18xz-y)$$

At this point you could substitute back the $y$ and $z$ to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of arithmetic:
$$\frac{36x(9x^2+3)(2x-8)-2(9x^2+3)^2}{(2x-8)^2}=\frac{ 18x\cdot \color{#66F}{2(9x^2+3)}(2x-8)-\color{#66F} {2(9x^2+3)}(9x^2+3)}{(2x-8)^2}= $$
$$=\frac{ 2(9x^2+3)[18x(2x-8)- (9x^2+3)]}{(2x-8)^2} $$

Comment: Thanks for the help!